# parsing and semantic analysis using CUP - Access parser stack

Tags: parsing, cup

I have a rule in my grammar such as

```
A -> B C D E    {: ...some actions... :}
```

;

```
D -> /*empty*/    {: some actions using attributes of B and C :}
```

;

To implement the actions associated with production rule of D, I need to access the parser stack. How can I do that in CUP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite your grammar:

```
A  -> A1 E
A1 -> B C D
```

If the action for the first production requires `B` and `C` as well, then the semantic value of `A1` will have to be more complicated in order to pass the semantic values through.